# Laravel observe after save fully completes?

Tags: laravel-4

In Laravel 4.2 you can bind an observe in your model:

```
public static function boot() {
    parent::boot();
    self::observe(new BookingObserver);
}

class BookingObserver {

    public function saved($model) {
        dump($model);
        die("i hath save");
    }
}
```

This fires when `->save()` is called on your model.

The problem is that my model is rather complex. After I call save, I save some related models too. I will need access to those in my observer, but the event is called too early.

Is there a way to delay calling observer methods until my controller actions complete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this situation, you should fire a [custom event](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/events) at the point in your controller where you want things to occur.

```
// in your controller
Event::fire('something.happened', array($model));

// in your app's bootstrap, perhaps
Event::listen('something.happened', function($model) {
    // do your thing here
});
```